# Geth on ios and RPC protocol

Tags: go-ethereum, light-clients, rpc, ios

I'm using Geth Objective-C API on ios and would like to start the node with RPC protocol enabled.

Is it possible and if yes how?

Comment: I think you can just use `geth --rpc`

Comment: I'm not running it as command but via the Objective-C API, so this won't work.

Comment: Then please update your question to add this detail .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15903)